# What is the best way to do case statement in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to convert my scripts into Ansible for automation. I am stuck in understanding loops or the "with_items" use case.

The original bash script:

```
for i in apple banana orange; do
    case $i in
      apple) export var="var.1:apple1,var.2:apple2" ;;
      banana) export var="var.1:banana1,var.2:banana2,var.3:banana3" ;;
      orange) export var="var.1:orange1" ;;
    esac

    echo "$i"
```

What I have tried so far:

```
VARS file:
fruits:
  - name: apple
    var: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - apple1
      - apple2
  - name: banana
    var: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - banana1
      - banana2
      - banana3
  - name: orange
    var: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - orange1
```

```
TASKS file:
- include_vars: vars.yml

- debug:
    msg: "{{ fruits }}"

- name: output in shell using echo 
  shell: |
    echo "{{ fruits.name }}" ;
    echo "{{ fruits.var }}"
  loop: "{{ fruits }}"
```

Outputs:

```
The output from include_vars task:
{
    "ansible_included_var_files": [
        "/etc/ansible/roles/openssl/tasks/vars.yml"
    ],
    "ansible_facts": {
        "fruits": [
            {
                "var": "{{ item }}",
                "name": "apple",
                "with_items": [
                    "apple1",
                    "apple2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "var": "{{ item }}",
                "name": "banana",
                "with_items": [
                    "banana1",
                    "banana2",
                    "banana3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "var": "{{ item }}",
                "name": "orange",
                "with_items": [
                    "orange1"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "changed": false
}
```

Debug

```
debug task failed
{
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/roles/openssl/tasks/main.yml': line 262, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- debug:\n  ^ here\n",
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

I know that Yaml are space sensitive and formatting is important. I am a novice at writing playbooks and any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With the [dictionary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics)

```
fruits:
  apple:
    - apple1
    - apple2
  banana:
    - banana1
    - banana2
    - banana3
  orange:
    - orange1
```

the [loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-dict)

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        vars.yml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ fruits|dict2items }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```
"msg": "orange [u'orange1']"
"msg": "apple [u'apple1', u'apple2']"
"msg": "banana [u'banana1', u'banana2', u'banana3']"
```

---

It's possible to reference the items in the dictionary. For example

```
- debug:
    var: fruits.banana
- debug:
    var: fruits.apple.1
```

gives

```
"fruits.banana": [
    "banana1", 
    "banana2", 
    "banana3"
]

"fruits.apple.1": "apple2"
```